# error attempting to setState - was working. Broken with recent update

Tags: typescript, react-native, lint, setstate

I am updating react-native and running into some broken code that was working before. Might be a simple typescript issue. Maybe something bigger.

I have tried reworking this to other given examples and everything looks correct but it will not build.

**Definitions**

```
export interface PositionListItemProps extends ViewProperties {
    position: typeof PositionModel.Type,
    first?: boolean
}

export interface PositionListItemState {
    showAll: boolean,
    comparing: boolean,
    position: typeof PositionModel.Type
}
```

My SetState: `this.state = state || { showAll: false, comparing: false, position: posit }`

**Broken method: (This is what I have)**

```
setViewedSubmission(subId: string) {
    this.setState(currentState => ({
        ...currentState,
        position: {
            ...currentState.position,
            candidates: currentState.position.candidates.map(
                c => c.submissionId === subId ? {
                    ...c,
                    viewedSubmission: true
                } : c
            )
        }
    }))
}
```

This is what was working (basically same as above)

```
this.setState(currentState => ({
    ...currentState,
    position: {
        ...currentState.position,
        candidates: currentState.position.candidates.map((c) => ({
            ...c,
            viewedSubmission: (c.submissionId === subId ? true : c.viewedSubmission)
        }))
    }
}))
```

The error I am getting is quite long but is as follows:

```
Argument of type '(currentState: Readonly<PositionListItemState>) => { position: { candidates: { viewedSubmission: boolean; display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; ... 25 more ...; $treenode?: any; }[]; ... 7 more ...; $treenode?: any; }; showAll: boolean; comparing: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PositionListItemState | ((prevState: Readonly<PositionListItemState>, props: PositionListItemProps) => PositionListItemState | Pick<PositionListItemState, "position" | "showAll" | "comparing">) | Pick<...>'.
  Type '(currentState: Readonly<PositionListItemState>) => { position: { candidates: { viewedSubmission: boolean; display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; ... 25 more ...; $treenode?: any; }[]; ... 7 more ...; $treenode?: any; }; showAll: boolean; comparing: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Readonly<PositionListItemState>, props: PositionListItemProps) => PositionListItemState | Pick<PositionListItemState, "position" | "showAll" | "comparing">'.
    Type '{ position: { candidates: { viewedSubmission: boolean; display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; userId: string; timeOff: string; lastName: string; firstName: string; ... 21 more ...; $treenode?: any; }[]; ... 7 more ...; $treenode?: any; }; showAll: boolean; comparin...' is not assignable to type 'PositionListItemState | Pick<PositionListItemState, "position" | "showAll" | "comparing">'.
      Type '{ position: { candidates: { viewedSubmission: boolean; display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; userId: string; timeOff: string; lastName: string; firstName: string; ... 21 more ...; $treenode?: any; }[]; ... 7 more ...; $treenode?: any; }; showAll: boolean; comparin...' is not assignable to type 'Pick<PositionListItemState, "position" | "showAll" | "comparing">'.
        Types of property 'position' are incompatible.
          Type '{ candidates: { viewedSubmission: boolean; display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; userId: string; timeOff: string; lastName: string; firstName: string; ... 21 more ...; $treenode?: any; }[]; ... 7 more ...; $treenode?: any; }' is not assignable to type '{ display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; needId: string; unit: string; discipline: string; specialty: string; shift: string; candidates: IObservableArray<{ display: ...; ... 16 more ...; loading: ...; } & { ...; } & IStateTreeNode> & ISnapshottable<...>; } & { ...;...'.
            Type '{ candidates: { viewedSubmission: boolean; display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; userId: string; timeOff: string; lastName: string; firstName: string; ... 21 more ...; $treenode?: any; }[]; ... 7 more ...; $treenode?: any; }' is not assignable to type '{ display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; needId: string; unit: string; discipline: string; specialty: string; shift: string; candidates: IObservableArray<{ display: ...; ... 16 more ...; loading: ...; } & { ...; } & IStateTreeNode> & ISnapshottable<...>; }'.
              Types of property 'candidates' are incompatible.
                Type '{ viewedSubmission: boolean; display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; userId: string; timeOff: string; lastName: string; firstName: string; photoUrl: any; ... 20 more ...; $treenode?: any; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IObservableArray<{ display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; userId: string; timeOff: string; lastName: string; firstName: string; viewedSubmission: boolean; photoUrl: any; ... 10 more ...; loading: boolean; } & { ...; } & IStateTreeNode> & ISnapshottable<...>'.
                  Type '{ viewedSubmission: boolean; display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; userId: string; timeOff: string; lastName: string; firstName: string; photoUrl: any; ... 20 more ...; $treenode?: any; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IObservableArray<{ display: { title: ...; description: ...; } & { getSnapshot(): unknown; } & IStateTreeNode; userId: string; timeOff: string; lastName: string; firstName: string; viewedSubmission: boolean; photoUrl: any; ... 10 more ...; loading: boolean; } & { ...; } & IStateTreeNode>': spliceWithArray, observe, intercept, clear, and 4 more.ts(2345)
```

*** UPDATE *** 
The following code doesn't throw errors, so does this look correct? I have some other build issues before I can test it.

```
setViewedSubmission(subId: string) {
        this.setState(currentState => ({
            ...currentState,
            position: {
                ...currentState.position,
                candidates: {
                    ...currentState.position.candidates,
                    viewedSubmission: currentState.position.candidates.map((c) => {
                        c.submissionId === subId ? true : c.viewedSubmission
                    })
                }
            }
        }))
    }
```

Comment: I should note that I am also going from Babel 6 to Babel 7. I think the issue is in there somewhere. Babel 7 is proving to be a challenge for this project.

Comment: Can you share the type of `PositionModel.Type`?

Comment: `code` export const PositionModel = types.model('Position', {
    display: TitleDescriptionModel,
    needId: types.optional(types.string, ''),
    unit: types.optional(types.string, ''),
    discipline: types.optional(types.string, ''),
    specialty: types.optional(types.string, ''),
    shift: types.optional(types.string, ''),
    candidates: types.maybe(types.array(CandidateModel))
})
.actions(self => {
    return {
        getSnapshot() {
            return getSnapshot(self)
        }
    }
})`code`

I didn't write this part of the code. Unsure the syntax

Comment: @Rengers thanks for editing the formatting. I am not sure why it formats correctly and sometimes it doesn't. I feel like I am doing what it says to do to display code but it doesn't always work. lol